# networkdays function not with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a date breaker and I need to calculate the working days excluding also bank holidays. I have used netwokingday function in vba but it seems not picking up the named range for the bank holidays. here is a piece of my code:

```
    For i = 2 To new_Endrow
    begin = Range("F" & i)
    finish = Range("G" & i)

    If finish <> "" Then

     Range("H" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(begin, finish, UKholidays)

    End If


Next
```

[image]

Bear in mind "begin" and "finish" are short dates and UKholidays is the name range which picks only the first column of the table shown excluding the title.
When I used the same function in the sheet as normal cell function rather that code with VBA it worked perfectly using the same sintax (=NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1,UKholidays), obviously A1 and B1 eing "begin" and "finish" respectively)

Comment: It should be `Range("UKHolidays")`

Comment: thank you @Variatus it works perfectly. How can I give you credits/points?

Comment: Thank you. Please mark the answer I posted as "Selected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of existing I recommend the following change.

```
Cells(i, "H").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(begin, finish, Range("UKholidays"))
```

Using the syntax `Range("H" + i)` is cumbersome if rows or column numbers are calculated. The preferable way to address single cells if `Cells([Row], [Column])`. VBA will accept the column in string format, like `Cells(i, "H")` but, obviously, this will have to be converted to `Cells(i, 8)` because Excel works with numbers, not strings.

Also, I urge you to address the `Value` property if you mean the `Value` property. It's the default and Excel/VBA will "understand" if you omit it. The problem is that `Cells(i, 8)`, the range, and `Cells(i, 8)`, its value, are indistinguishable to *you* and it's you who will be confused when Excel doesn't catch the meaning you intended.